# learning linear algebra in a brief amount of time

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I'm trying learn linear algebra in a brief amount of time. so  I'm looking for a book on linear algebra which is succinct, enlighting and self-contained.
Based on your personal experience which book you think is best to learn linear algebra in a brief amount of time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good books to learn Linear Algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2921922/good-books-to-learn-linear-algebra). Important is that th book is good. How fast you learn does not depend on the book then.

Comment: David C. Lay - Linear Algebra and Its Applications 5th ed. (Lay, Lay, Mcdonald) Pretty good one

Comment: Linear Algebra is best learned slowly.

Comment: Consider Treil's [Linear Algebra Done Wrong](https://www.math.brown.edu/~treil/papers/LADW/LADW.html)

Comment: @GerryMyerson yeah but I'm learning it to study other courses in physics

Comment: Then maybe you should be asking physics people for their recommendations.